# How to add a variable column length in a excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using a formula (mentioned below) in Excel where I need the length of the column to be increased of decreased with a specific value given in a cell (this value is calculate by a formula).

```
=IF(AE99>0,AF99+SUM(AF93:AF98),AF99)
```

[image]

Here I want to increase or decrease the length of (AF93:AF98) by a value given in eg. cell C2.  Suppose it's 6. so the length of the column is 6 rows or C2 is 30, length of the column in formula is then 30 rows.

Additional info:

In the picture, AE99 is the time. I want the the formula to check; if there is a value in AE99 it adds previous 6 rows to the corresponding cell of AE that is AF. Now I want the length or height (however its called) that is AF93:AF98 to be varied by a value given in another, completely different cell for example  it is 10, so the length of the column would be AF88:AF98.

Comment: So if `C2 = 6` is the range to use `AF93:AF98`? and if `C2=30` then is the range to use `AF93:AF122` or`AF69:AF98` (both are 30 rows high)?

Comment: I have no idea what you’re saying. Take a deep breath. Imagine that you’re explaining this to somebody who isn’t you (because we can’t read your mind). What do you mean by “the length of the column”? Are you referring to the fact that the AF93:AF98 range is six rows high? What do you mean by “the length of the column is 6 rows or C2 is 30”? Is that meant to be two separate sentences? What does AE99 have to do with the question? What result do you want to get? (I can’t figure it out from your example.) Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I would expect, based on context, that the desired change is in the column width, rather than "length."

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: yes you are absolutely right AF69:AF98 is the right one here. i want the formula to add previous 30 cells or whatever number to the cell where the formula is applied

Comment: @ Scott and @ fred_dot_u : i hope my edit makes it clear now

Comment: @osk, if I'm not  wrong you are trying to increase or  decrease the ROW HEIGHT using the Cell value, am I correct?

Comment: @Rajesh S: yes, if you see the picture, i want to change the height of purple selected cells

Comment: If you wish I can suggest you VBA solution will help you to increase/decrease height of cells according to the Value entered in the Cell. Like if A1 has 12 the Excel will set height of the cell to 12 ! Will this work for you ?

Comment: yes please, i can also include VBA solution in the file, couldnt figure out through formulas anyways

Comment: I just cleaned up the question a little, but I haven't got a clue as to what you are asking.  It might help to show a before and after.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula should do the job:

```
=IF(AF99>0,AF99+SUM(INDIRECT("AF" & 99-(MAX(C2,1) & ":AF98")),AF99)
```